# Windows update - error 80240034, how to fix?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have a PC with Windows 10 x64 Home which fails to install Windows cumulative updates with error code 0x80070002, but if I open the Update History, a different error code is reported there, 0x80240034.

I have tried deleting `\Windows\SoftwareDistribution` folder, but it doesn't help - after I start Windows Update service again, the update runs for a while (obviously re-downloading files I have deleted), then fails again with the same error.

I also performed a [clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-da2f9573-6eec-00ad-2f8a-a97a1807f3dd), but it didn't change anything.

Does anyone know what this error code means and what possible actions I could take to fix it?

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). Run the Windows Update Troubleshooter in *Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Additional troubleshooters > Windows Update > Run*.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the hint. `dism` complained about missing files, so I tried to share the Windows folder on my other laptop and run `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:\\other_laptop\windows /limitaccess`, but it still complains that "The source files could not be found". Do you know if it's possible to use a network share as a source with `dism`, or do I have to copy the files on a removable disk first?

Answer (score 0):

As `dism` has found errors, Windows is missing pieces.
This is abnormal, and you should check seriously if your computer
wasn't infected.

To return Windows to a working state would require to
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
This is exactly equal to doing a major upgrade of Windows, so take
precautions and backups of your data.

Answer (score 0):

I started by running `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` which reported missing or corrupted files (I couldn't understand which ones though, the log file is not easily readable). Then I tried to "bootstrap" the system using files from another laptop which is also running Windows 10:

- On the other laptop I shared the `C:\Windows` folder
- On the target laptop I have run `dism`

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:\\other_laptop\windows /limitaccess
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:\\other_laptop\windows\SysSxS /limitaccess
```

The progress went further than the first time but `dism` was still failing to complete. I assume it was because the other laptop already had recent updates installed.

I ended up downloading [Windows update assistant](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/windows-10-update-assistant-3550dfb2-a015-7765-12ea-fba2ac36fb3f), which was able to perform the update.

Comment: You forced through one update, but I'm not sure that the underlying problem was fixed.

Comment: @harrymc I have run `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` again, and now it reports "The restore operation has completed successfully", and the system is installing additional updates on its own. It seems that forcing that one cumulative update was enough to get it going. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution for this can be:

Solution 1. Turn OFF the Windows Developer Mode.
Solution 2. Run the Windows Update Troubleshooter.
Solution 3. Force Windows to re-create the Windows Update Store folder.
Solution 4. Update Windows 10 using the ISO file.